# Pushing data into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Alright, I've got this blank array of objects. 
I am dynamically finding every node in a web page and each node is going to have it's own object and properties.
I need a way to throw the values I need into their respective objects property

So, for example, I find the `body` node. I now have a special little object for this node. I need to throw pretty much everything about this little guy into his object's properties.

So I pretty much need it to render like this:

Turning this:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin:0; padding:0;" title="My Title">
        <p>some text</p>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Into this:

```
this.nodesInfo = [ // All nodes in the page's DOM
    {
        type: 'body', // ex: body, section, aside, div, etc.
        id: 'myID', // the Id of that element
        class: ['myClass1', 'myClass2'], // the class/class' of that element
        depth: '2', // the level in the page's DOM in which that element sits, this will be an integer
        parent: 'html', // that elements direct parent Node 
        children:['div.wrapper', 'p', 'footer'], // any child Nodes that, that element may be a parent to
        text: '', // the text inside that element if any exists
        attributes: ["style=margin:0; padding:0;", "title='My Title'"] // all attributes of this node
    }
];
```

It would of course cycle through each node it discovered and do this for each node accordingly, until it ran out of nodes.

The class, children, and attributes properties are arrays for the simple possibility of multiples of any of these. Everything else is just a string since a node can't have more than one ID, title, or direct parent tag.

If a node does not contain some of these properties then that property would remain blank/null/undefined.

---

My question is simple. Is this possible, if not would I instead have to create each object individually and the push them into my `nodesInfo` array?

I think the easiest way to go about this would be making an object of each Node and then pushing them all (once they are all created) into an array.

Comment: Why do you need this? There's a resource called [The DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model).

Comment: I was doing something like this the other day, check my answer.

Comment: @paislee I'm working on a project to help better visualize a websites DOM map. I think it would help in the navigation of that sites DOM when it comes to CSS and jQuery interaction and manipulation. But thanks for the useless comment anyway. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was building something like this the other night. This should work and you can add more stuff easily. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/UHbMa/

```
$.fn.buildTree = function() {
    var tree = {};
    this.find('*').andSelf().each(function(i, v) {
        var parents = $(this).parents().length - 1,
            depth = 0;
        while (depth < parents) {
            depth++;
        }
        tree[v.tagName.toLowerCase() + '(' + i + ')'] = {
            id: (v.id) ? '#' + v.id : '',
            className: (v.className) ? '.' + v.className.replace(' ', '.') : '',
            depth: depth
        };
    });
    return tree;
};


// Then you can do this...

var tree = $('#element').buildTree();
for (var tag in tree) {
    // Get your variables
    var tag.match(/\w+/), // Get rid of `(n)`
        id = tree[tag].id,
        className = tree[tag].className,
        depth = tree[tag].depth;
    html = 'something'; 

    // Bla bla
}
```

Comment: I guess this would end up creating my object for each node, so I could then push them into my array. I guess this will have to work for now, or at least until I(or anybody else) can come up with a different solution. Thanks! =D

Comment: Well, it basically accepts whatever collection of objects you want to throw in and you get one big `tree{}` object with as many tags as the collection has, each `tag` being an object with properties itself. You can extend this infinitely...I posted this code the other night.

Comment: Yeah, the other night I was looking for the thing I'm building now. I never ended up finding it, so I decided to begin building it lol. Also, I noticed an error that it doesn't seem to be documenting the existence of the 3 divs inside subChild1. (the anotherChild1, 2, and 3). I haven't been able to figure out why yet though.